# MySQL stored procedure or function to return a person's name in a specific format

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, stored-functions

I'm a little fuzzy on the difference between stored procedures and functions. I have an employee directory database with a data table containing, among other details, the following name fields:

```
first_name, varchar(45)
mi, char(3)
last_name, varchar(45)
suffix, varchar(10)
```

I'd like to be able to have a function/procedure return the full name in

*last_name* (*suffix*), *first_name* (*mi*)

format, where the fields in parentheses are NULL optional in the table. I can build the formatted name string in PHP with

```
SELECT last_name, suffix, first_name, mi from employee;
```

, then use a series of conditionals to test for empty suffix and mi fields. But, I'd like to be able to use an SQL statement like

```
SELECT getDisplayName() WHERE last_name LIKE '%Smith%';
```

to return a result like

```
Smith III, John Q
Smith, Susanne L
Smithers, Waylon
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or at least tell me if I need a function or procedure?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDisplayName;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getDisplayName(last_name text, suffix text, first_name text, mi text)
  RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE name text;
  SET name = '';
  IF last_name IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET name = last_name;
  END IF;

  IF suffix IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET name = CONCAT(name, ' ', suffix);
  END IF;

  IF first_name IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET name = CONCAT(name, ', ', first_name);
  END IF;

  IF mi IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET name = CONCAT(name, ' ', mi);
  END IF;

  RETURN name;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So your select will look like:

```
SELECT getDisplayName(last_name, suffix, first_name, mi) FROM employee WHERE last_name LIKE '%Smith%';
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.
Is there a way I'd be able to get the same result without having to specify the four parameters? Or is it a scope issue where if I don't give the variables to the function it can't access them?

Comment: You are right "it a scope issue where if I don't give the variables to the function it can't access them"

Comment: Great, thank you @alexander. Thanks again for the function. I have to tweak it a bit because "IS NOT NULL" isn't the same as an empty string. It's a great start though.